# Permanently replacing API server certificates

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, kubernetes-apiserver, microk8s

I have microK8S cluster, and expose the API server at my domain. 
The `server.crt` and `server.key` in `/var/snap/microk8s/1079/certs` need to be replaced with the ones that include my domain.
Otherwise, as expected, i get the error:

`Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate is valid for kubernetes, kubernetes.default, kubernetes.default.svc, kubernetes.default.svc.cluster, kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local, not mydonaim.com`

With the help of cert-manager I have produced certificates and replaced them, my system works well.

**Problem:** every time server is restarted, `server.crt` and `server.key` are generated again in 
`/var/snap/microk8s/1079/certs`. My custom certs are deleted, making API server unreachable remotely. 
How can I stop the system from doing that all the time?

**Workaround?**
Should I place my certificates elsewhere and edit config files like `/var/snap/microk8s/1079/args/kube-controller-manager` with the path to those certificates? Are those config files auto-replaced as well?

#### Cluster information:

- Kubernetes version: 1.16.3
- Cloud being used: Bare metal, single-node
- cluster Installation method: Ubuntu Server with Snaps
- Host OS: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like there is [an existing issue](https://github.com/ubuntu/microk8s/issues/421#issuecomment-482105218) that describes copying and modifying the `/var/snap/microk8s/current/certs/csr.conf.template` to include any extra IP or DNS entries for the generated certificates

Comment: Yup, the devs kindly answered my question. I should have updated this question

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware of the proposed updates in https://discuss.kubernetes.io/t/services-and-ports/11263/6. The following command was required to run in my env:

```
sudo microk8s refresh-certs
```